# Convert CreateGUID from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am modifying a classic asp.net webforms project.

I am trying to use this vb6 function in my Footer.ascx.vb in a function:

Here is the function:

```
Function CreateGUID()
        Dim tmpTemp
        tmpTemp = Right(String(4, 48) & Year(Now()), 4)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4, 48) & Month(Now()), 2)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4, 48) & Day(Now()), 2)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4, 48) & Hour(Now()), 2)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4, 48) & Minute(Now()), 2)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4, 48) & Second(Now()), 2)
        CreateGUID = tmpTemp
    End Function
```

Does anyone know how to convert this to vb.net?  Thank You.

Comment: What you want to do exactly with your “String”  function?

Comment: Hi G3, I do not have a "String" function.   The CreateGUID function should return a guid.  Please refer to this microsoft document for more details on using above function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/create-guids-asp

Comment: Yes but that is vb6

Comment: You are programming in NET

Comment: I see.  Notice in my comment I mentioned "I havent used vb.net in a while".  I did not realize it was vb6.  I will update to mention "How to convert to vb.net"

Comment: Oh ok use as follows `Right(New String("4"c, 48) & Month(Now()), 2)`

Comment: "4" is the char you are going to use and 48 the length of the new String

Comment: Don't forget `Option Strict On` as tmpTemp need to be declared with a type ;)

Comment: Hi G3, I created an answer.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Put this  `Dim tmpTemp As Something`  `String` in your case.. Correct procedure :)

Comment: And I'm not G3. I'm Wireless.....

Comment: That's not a GUID.  It's a time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to mimic the original behavior:

```
Function CreateGUID() As String
    Return Now().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
End Function
```

But that's more of a timestamp, and not really a GUID at all. If you actually want a GUID:

```
Function CreateGUID() As String
    Return Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer with the help of G3:

```
 Function CreateGUID()
        Dim tmpTemp
        tmpTemp = Right(New String("4"c, 48) & Year(Now()), 4)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(New String("4"c, 48) & Month(Now()), 2)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(New String("4"c, 48) & Day(Now()), 2)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(New String("4"c, 48) & Hour(Now()), 2)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(New String("4"c, 48) & Minute(Now()), 2)
        tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(New String("4"c, 48) & Second(Now()), 2)
        CreateGUID = tmpTemp
    End Function
```

Please let me know if I missed anything.

**Updated and improved suggestion based on G3's comment below:**

```
Function CreateGUID() As String
    Dim guid As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
    CreateGUID = guid.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Let me add something else: The best way to create a guid is  `Dim g As Guid = Guid.NewGuid() : Debug.WriteLine(g.ToString)`

Comment: Right, and how is the whole application now going to work with a VERY different and VAST different guid string compared to the existing code, data and design?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you wanted the same code, then you really don't have to change it.

The only change would be the char number 4 (ctrl-d). That would thus become this:

```
Function CreateGUID()

    Dim tmpTemp As String
    Dim s As String = New String(Chr(48), 4)

    tmpTemp = Right(s & Year(Now()), 4)
    tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(s & Month(Now()), 2)
    tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(s & Day(Now()), 2)
    tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(s & Hour(Now()), 2)
    tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(s & Minute(Now()), 2)
    tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(s & Second(Now()), 2)
    CreateGUID = tmpTemp

End Function
```

So, VBA/VB6 the params for string are FLIPPED - everything else will work the same.

As others pointed out - you could use the built in command - but it will be formatted somewhat different, and will include "-" (4 of them), and will also include alpha chars a-f.

The original string was only 0-9,and 14 chars long.

If you use the vb.net guid, then it will be 36 chars long, and include alpha-numeric - a VAST different result for the code to operate against.

and that could in theory break existing code.